# A question about permutation group and its subgroups

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I have these two permutations of $S_{12}$:

$\alpha =(1\;3\;5\;7\;9)(2\;4\;6\;8\;10)(11\;12)$

$\beta=(1\;6\;8\;10)(2\;3\;5\;7)(4\;9)(11\;12)$

I need to prove that if $G$ is a subgroup of $S_{12}$ and $\alpha,\beta\in G$ then exist a permutation $\gamma \in G$ such that $\gamma(1) = 4$

Any hint? I have no idea how to demonstrate it.

Comment: The answer seems pretty straightforward.  Now that you've fixed the error in the permutation you've written down, do you still need help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** In $\alpha$ you see that $1$ and $9$ are in a cycle together, and in $\beta$ you see that $9$ and $4$ are in a cycle together, so...

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want to mean but the only thing I've noticed is that such a permutation can be obtained from the product of $\beta\alpha^4$ because $\alpha^4$ sends 1 to 9 and then $\beta$ sends 9 to 4...

Comment: That is precisely what I meant; if two elements are in a cycle together (in disjoint cycle notation), then applying that permutations enough times maps one to the other. Here four times $\alpha$ and one time $\beta$ is enough times.

Comment: Oh, nice. And this may be sufficient to give a solid answer to the question asked? There's a specific reason why G is used? Why do I need to know that the two permutations belong to a subgroup of $S_{12}$?

Comment: You need to show that there exists such a $\gamma\in G$. To show that $\beta\alpha^4\in G$ you need to use that $G$ is a (sub)group.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Apply $\alpha$ enough times and then apply $\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: if $G$ is a subgroup that contains these two elements, then $G$ contains any multiple and power of them. Then use cycle decomposition of your elements.